# How Remove pre_user_nicename Filter WP

Tags: wordpress

i what to remove this filter:

wp-includes/user.php line 2158 function wp_insert_user

```
$user_nicename = apply_filters( 'pre_user_nicename', $user_nicename );

if ( mb_strlen( $user_nicename ) > 50 ) {
return new WP_Error( 'user_nicename_too_long', __( 'Nicename may not be longer than 50 characters.' ) );
}
```

I wrote this code but it doesn't remove the filter:

`remove_filter('pre_user_nicename', 'wp_insert_user');`

what is the problem?

Comment: It may be helpful for you to indicate precisely what functionality/logic you are wanting to remove, so we have context and can be more precise in our answers.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how [`remove_filter()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/remove_filter/) works: the second parameter would be a callback that's been applied to the filter, not the name of the function that contains the function.

If you want to remove all callbacks applied to a particular filter, you can use [`remove_all_filters()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/remove_all_filters/) (untested):

```php
remove_all_filters( 'pre_user_nicename' );
```

Comment: i test. not worked

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the filter. The problem is that this condition must be removed

`if ( mb_strlen( $user_nicename ) > 50 ) { return new WP_Error( 'user_nicename_too_long', __( 'Nicename may not be longer than 50 characters.' ) ); }`